# Linq Expression gets Convert function inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

In my project for certain properties the expression for the form (x=>x.property) comes out as (x=>Convert(x.property)) at runtime as shown :

[image]

It depends upon property type, double and DateTime seem to be the culprit. Works fine for string properties (e.g Speed and ForeColour are both strings)

Why is it coming out this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`double` and `DateTime` are value types. The compiler is using `Expression.Convert` to represent the boxing operation, basically.

`string` is already a reference type, so no conversion is required.

You can see the same thing in normal code:

```
double d = 0.5;
string s = "hello";

object o1 = d;
object o2 = s;
```

... compiles to:

```
// d = 0.5
IL_0001:  ldc.r8     0.5
IL_000a:  stloc.0

// s = "hello"
IL_000b:  ldstr      "hello"
IL_0010:  stloc.1

// o1 = d - boxing!
IL_0011:  ldloc.0
IL_0012:  box        [mscorlib]System.Double
IL_0017:  stloc.2

// o2 = s - no boxing required!
IL_0018:  ldloc.1
IL_0019:  stloc.3
```

Comment: Thank you so very much jon. Is there a way I can accept these expressions with generics since "Expression<Func<VehicleNotification,DateTime>> test1 = (x => x.GpsDateTime);" works but I cannot accept a list of these. Something like "List<Expression<Func<T,object>>> properties" is what I was planning to use.

Comment: Figured out a way: Instead of accepting a List. I should design a fluent API to add each expression then each function call can be generics driven. Thanks.